# Broke my local git repo

Tags: git, github, gitignore, git-add

For whatever reason my .gitignore is failing to ignore my `node_modules` directory. When I do a `git status` it's returning a bunch of deleted and modified files that are under a directory it's supposed to ignore, and it's not picking up files I've added since the last commit.

What am I doing wrong?

The repo is [here](https://github.com/gh0st/ng2do-mean-app-arvindr21).

My `.gitignore` is here:

```
node_modules
.idea

# compiled output
/public/vendor/my-app/dist
/public/vendor/my-app/tmp

# dependencies
bower_components

# IDEs and editors
/.idea

# misc
/public/vendor/my-app/.sass-cache
/public/vendor/my-app/connect.lock
/public/vendor/my-app/coverage/*
/public/vendor/my-app/lib/peerconnection.log
/public/vendor/my-app/npm-debug.log
/public/vendor/my-app/testem.log
/public/vendor/my-app/typings

# e2e
/public/vendor/my-app/e2e/*.js
/public/vendor/my-app/e2e/*.map

#System Files
.DS_Store
```

Is there anything else I can paste that would be of help?

Comment: Your repo link is 404
Is gitignore definitely in the root of your project ?

Comment: Yes but there is another .gitignore in a different directory. Could they be conflicting?

Comment: Where are the files it's not picking up located?

Comment: They're under public/vendor. What's weird is when in Atom, this public/vendor folder has a funny icon on it. Like a smaller folder inside a bigger folder.

Comment: Could you give a complete account of the commands you use to add the files under `public/vendor` and the responses from git, preferably using some `git status` commands in between?

Comment: I could give you the commands but not the responses...I've already cleared screen on terminal a handful of times. I'd only be giving you command history.

Comment: The files in `public/vendor` have already been added to your repo in a previous commit? So they are tracked by git? And now you modify these files and you don't see these modifications pop up when you use git status?

Comment: @Nils_M correct

Comment: Please check if the files pop up when you do `git ls-tree -r master --name-only`, replacing `master` with your current branch. This will tell you if they are tracked.

Comment: I see `public/vendor` but not the files and folders inside it.

Comment: If I `cd public/vendor` and try a `git add my-app` I get `fatal: Pathspec 'my-app/' is in submodule 'public/vendor'`. Is that my problem? What's going on there?

Comment: When I `git ls-tree -r master --name-only` I see `public/vendor` but nothing inside it.

Comment: Did you check the new part of my answer regarding that topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have tracked files in the subdirectory `node_modules`. Adding a directory to the `.gitignore` file does not untrack these files. You have to do that yourself.

Use

```
git rm --cached -r node_modules
```

and follow up with a commit to delete all files in `node_modules`. Using `--cached`, they are only deleted from git (specifically the index and, after comitting, the repository) and not from your filesystem.

For the second part of your question, the comments you gave lead me to the conclusion that you are using the `submodule` feature and that the directory `public/vendor` is actually a submodule. Please refer to the git documentation [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules). You can not add files from submodules to the main git repository as that would break the distinction between the original repo and the submodule.

Comment: So after I run `git rm --cached -r node_modules` I did a `cd node_modules` and then a `rm -rf *`. After that I did a `git status` and all those files are still showing up as waiting to be committed for deletion. Must I commit that? Also the other files that were under `public/vendor` are not showing up for staging. Any idea what's going on there?

Comment: ah ok, so you wanted to get rid of all files in `node_modules` even in your filesystem. You could have left out the `--cached` flag and it would have done what you want without an extra `rm -rf`. You have to commit the file deletions, yes. Right now, the files are deleted in your index and in your working directory. You have to commit these deletions to get them (the deletions) into the repository.

Comment: I'd prefer to ignore my `node_modules` directory.

Comment: You deleted all data in it. Is that what you mean by ignore?

Comment: No, I just don't want git tracking the files inside `node_modules`. I'll run `npm i` again after all those files have been untracked by git. If there are a lot of modules I want to load into the app I don't want them to be source controlled.

Comment: Then my answer is right and you shouldn't have run `rm -rf *` in `node_modules`. This was unnecessary. The commands I listed would have made git untrack the files in `node_modules` without deleting them from your filesystem.

Comment: Ok that's fine. I can still `npm i` to reinstall them.

Answer (score 0):

Try a slash on the end:

```
node_modules/
```